# Why does jQuery complain about an "invalid left-hand assignment"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function auditUpdate(newval) {
    jQuery("#audit").val() = newval;
    jQuery("#auditForm").submit();
}
```

Why do I get an error where I try to assign newval to the `#audit` value?

Comment: Well, the left-hand side of an assignment obviously has to be a reference. An assignment stores the value from the right-hand side into the reference on the left-hand side. The result of calling `val()` is a string, not a reference, hence the error.

Answer (score 7):

In jQuery you assign a new value with:

```
jQuery("#audit").val(newval);
```

`val()` without a variable works as a getter, not a setter.

Answer (score 6):

**jQuery** doesn't complain about it. But your JavaScript interpreter does. The line

```
jQuery("#audit").val() = newval;
```

is invalid JavaScript syntax. You can't assign a value to the result of a function call. Your code says "call `val`, get the return value -- and then assign `newval` to the return value." This makes no sense.

Instead:

```
function auditUpdate(newval) {
    jQuery("#audit").val(newval);
    jQuery("#auditForm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the right syntax would be:

```
jQuery("#audit").val(newval);
```

val is a function, that, when executed, can't be assigned a value like you try to do.